# Is there a name/terminology for binary codes with evenly spaced number of ones?

Tags: boolean-functions, it.information-theory, coding-theory, embeddings, boolean-matrix

I am generating a random binary matrix $A \in \{0, 1\}^{m \times n}$ with the number of ones in each row set to evenly spaced numbers from an interval. For example, if $n=50$, the number of ones for $m=5$ rows will be equal to $[ 1, 12, 25, 37, 50]$ i.e. $A$ will be a matrix with first row containing a single one, second row containing 12 ones, third containing 25 ones and so on. I was wondering if this style of construction is well-known and if there is a class of binary codes that it corresponds to?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are those numbers "evenly" spaced? define what you want. I see differences of 11, 13, 12, 13 in the sequence [1,12,25,37,50]

Comment: Thank you! probably the better word would be equally spread out? In the example, I want to keep adding ones so that it sum ups to n in the last row but if it helps figuring out some connection, considering exactly same numbers like [1, 12, 23, 34, 45] also works for me.